# Unable to install Google Earth on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, google-earth

> Make sure the lsb-core package is installed! Open a terminal from Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal (in the Panel) or from the Dash (in new Unity desktop) and type (or copy-paste) the following command into the terminal:
>
> sudo apt-get install lsb-core
>
> 64bit users: You should use this instead if installing the 32bit package
>
> sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 \
>       libglu1-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libxext6:i386 \
>       libxrender1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 lsb-core

All this recommended for the installation of Google Earth for older Ubuntu versions does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 anymore. Who can help?

Comment: Hi there. Have you managed to install it without any problems?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this I managed to do this in gnome Ubuntu LTS 16.04

```
wget -O google-earth.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/google-earth/google-earth.sh
chmod +x google-earth.sh;sudo ./google-earth.sh
```

If the font in Google Earth Ugly, we can add msttcorefonts using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

[image]

Comment: Same error as always. Google Earth crashes after some seconds with the error message:

Another crash happened while handling crash!

Answer (score 2):

## For 64 bit systems

```
sudo apt --yes install lsb-core

cd /tmp
mkdir google-earth && cd google-earth
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable*.deb

# Step to show Panoramio pictures
cd /opt/google/earth/free/
sudo wget https://googledrive.com/host/0B2F__nkihfiNalQzN0ZmcjBPTGs/ge7.1.1.1580-0.x86_64-new-qt-libs-debian7-ubuntu12.tar.xz
sudo tar xvf ge7.1.1.1580-0.x86_64-new-qt-libs-debian7-ubuntu12.tar.xz
```

## For 32 bit systems

```
sudo apt --yes install lsb-core

cd /tmp
mkdir google-earth && cd google-earth
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable*.deb
```

## Reference

http://blog.pztop.com/2016/04/28/Install-Google-Earth-on-Ubuntu-16-04/